# RegEx validation for dynamically created elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, onkeyup

I create `textbox` like the following on the fly :

```
 var dataInputBox = '<input type=text  name='+id+' id=datePicker maxlength='+maxlength+' title="'+tooltip+'" onKeyUp="inputFilter(this,"'+regex+'");/>';
```

and this is my javascript method :

```
function inputFilter(inputbox,regex) {
           txb.value = inputbox.value.replace(regex, "");
        }
```

regex value would be :  `"^(?![ ])(?=.*[\w]).{1,70}(?<!\s)$"` like wise I will be passing the different regex value and what I gave above is for `Alphanumeric`. I will be passing the different regex values like the above.

when I execute the above I get the text box and when I try to enter some values I get the following exception : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`

line number given at the console is not the correct one and I shows that the error is in `line number 2` if I remove `onKeyUp="inputFilter(this,"'+regex+'");` than I don't get this exception.

could some one help me on this please...

Comment: Seems like you have unbalanced quotes in your line number 2.

Comment: if I remove onKeyUp="inputFilter(this,"'+regex+'"); than I don't get this exception.

Comment: Seems like you have unbalanced quotes in that line.

Comment: @Jerry would you look in to this http://jsfiddle.net/meetantoalphi/T55RA/

Comment: @Jerry yes, but I will get the regex part dynamically passed to the method, It is not possible for me to get the control name like in your fiddle since everything is generated dynamically.

Comment: You can put the regex in a variable: http://jsfiddle.net/T55RA/2/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37588/discussion-between-anto-and-jerry)

Answer (score 0):

The error came from your regexpr : ^(?![ ])(?=.*[\w]).{1,70}(?

```
var r = /^(?![ ])(?=.*[\w]).{1,70}(?<!\s)$/;
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^(?![ ])(?=.*[\w]).{1,70}(?<!\s)$/: Invalid group
```

Maybe you mean :

```
^(?![ ])(?=.*[\w]).{1,70}(?!<!\s)$
```

Note the extra '!' in the last group : (?!